# equivalent or similar with die() in php

Tags: php

It's been awhile since I coded with PHP and I just completely forget what is something that we use to usually show errors in PHP, I mean something familiar with the `die()` function in PHP

Comment: Do you mean var_dump()?

Comment: Or maybe echo()?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `display_errors`?  But first check your error_reporting setting, and probably your error logs.  I find tailing a log helpful.